# Android GET_CONTENT Audio file

Tags: android, audio, android-intent

I face some probleam in following case:

```
LOAD_AUDIO_REQUEST_CODE = 1000;

Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
intent.setType("audio/*");
startActivityForResult(intent, LOAD_AUDIO_REQUEST_CODE);

public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
     Uri uri = data.getData();
     Log.i(TAG, "uri path : " uri.getPath());
}
```

In `onActivityResult` data path indicate `/document/audio:458`, but i want to get anothor path like a `/storage/emulated/0/Music/music0.mp3`.

How can I convert `/document/audio:458` to `/storage/.../music0.mp3`?

Answer (score 1):

> In onActivityResult data path indicate /document/audio:458.

You received a `content:` `Uri`. This is fairly normal on newer versions of Android. Future versions of Android might block `file:` `Uri` values.

> how can convert /document/audio:458 to /storage/..../music0.mp3

You don't. There does not have to be a file associated with a given `Uri`. That `Uri` might point to:

- A local file on external storage
- A local file on internal storage for the other app
- A local file on removable storage
- A local file that is encrypted and needs to be decrypted on the fly
- A stream of bytes held in a `BLOB` column in a database
- A piece of content that needs to be downloaded by the other app first
- ...and so on

Instead, use a `ContentResolver` and:

- `openInputStream()` to read in the bytes associated with the content
- `getType()` to get the MIME type associated with the content
- `query()` and the `OpenableColumns` to get the size and display name associated with the content